# Type in Gujarati in Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: input-method

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 and I want to type in Gujarati.
There are general ways showing the solution for Ubuntu 11.0 and above, but being new to Ubuntu, could not cop!
Please help....
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to install the Gujarati Language and use it using the below step-by-step guide:

1. First open <kbd>Settings</kbd>
2. Click on <kbd>Language Support</kbd>
3. In the Language Support window that appears click on <kbd>Install/Remove languages</kbd>
4. Search for `Gujarati` and tick on the box right to it.
5. Click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>
6. Close the settings screen and search for `iok` and open `iok -Indic Onscreen Keyboard`
7. In the bottom right, you can select `Gujarati language`
8. Open any text editor and press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to switch between language and start typing and enjoy...

Comment: Thanks Tejas! in fact I intended to type like we do using Google indic transliteration on windows